# How can I link a C++ library into an Objective-C program

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c

I have a C++ Library that I'd like to link against my iPhone project. How do I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I integrate my existing C++ library in iPhone application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308673/can-i-integrate-my-existing-c-library-in-iphone-application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just drag it in and make sure that the header files are available. That's it :) Make sure that the .a file (assuming that your library is a .a file) is listed on the build phases tab under "link binary with libraries".

Comment: And as always, don't forget to mark it as your answer :-) I've already had 20 upvotes today.

Comment: If possible, could you please upvote my question? I'll upvote yours.

Comment: Now that's cheating ;-) I'm only allowed to upvote very good questions and to be honest, a oneliner isn't one of them. But I did give the correct answer.

Comment: Hey, the answer function is there for a reason :-)

Comment: My question has been answered and my problem has been solved. Thank you!

Comment: You may also need to add `-lstdc++` to `Other linker flags`, if the library you're using links against the C++ standard library.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be sure the library is built for iOS, specifically for the architecture you intend to deploy on. For instance, an Armv7 will not work on the simulator or on a pre-armv7 device like the 3G. If you want this approach to work flawlessly you probably should build a .a library for all architectures, (armv6/armv7 i386) then combine them into a fat library with the "lipo" command. This assumes you have access to the source, of course. There was a post here on SO regarding exactly how to build a fat library from source. After you've done this then it would be a simple matter of drag/dropping it into Xcode along with the headers.