# can we use libraries written in c++ in iphone projects?

Tags: iphone, c++, html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

Can we integrate a library such a wkhtmltopdf written for linux in c++ into ios.I have heard we can integrate c++ code into iphone projects ie can we use the code or use the static library itself.how to accomplish this one.If this is not possible,is there any other good library to convert html to pdf.(other than  printing the uiwebview to pdf)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308673/integrate-c-library-into-iphone-app

Comment: @Maulik i didnt get any satisfactory answer from that link....man just dont mark anything as duplicate.Can u find atleast one way to integrate c++ into iphone project from that link?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about wkhtmltopdf in particular, but in this case you don't need to build a static library, just include the wkhtmltopdf sources in your project and get them to build. Then you should be able to use wkhtmltopdf by calling the wkhtmltopdf APIs.

Comment: Adding the c++ files into my application bundle and compiling itself causes many errors.Can u pls elaborate on how to compile multiple c++ files together with objective c files in xcode project

Comment: This is probably going to be a bigger issue than can be handled here. You'll have to figure out what is required to get the files to compile. It looks like iOS currently isn't supported. Perhaps if you ask someone involved with the wkhtmltopdf project they might help you.